# Alarm Clock -- Time Picker

Tags: c#, winforms, time, alarm, picker

I am trying to write a radio alarm clock as a bit of programming practice, I have successfully got a clock working in a line or two. When it comes however to having the use select an alarm time I don't know how to collect the information.

A date time picker can pass a date and time it would seem, but I can only figure out how to select the date which is the part I don't want.

Are there any other objects i can put on a form so a user can select a time to set the alarm?

Comment: Yeah I remember having to make a custom timepicker when I didn't care for the date. Essentially it was just a couple of NumericUpDown controls for hours and minutes. Use something like that and you shoudl be able to store the time info you need (you can limit them to 0 - 23 and 0 - 59 respectively)

Comment: Custom time picker, is that well document on MSDN? I have been unsuccessful at removing the date so far.

Comment: "Custom Time Picker" = one that I made myself. Just google ".net time pickers" and you can see what other people have made

Comment: I see its custom property now, I will have a look around for the formatting.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to manipulate only the Time with a `DateTimePicker`, the following code should work according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx):

```
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I wanted. Where did you find this out, I have been Google-ing around for a while and not come across it.

Thanks again :)